# Are these statements true in the following sets?

Tags: first-order-logic

I'd like to confirm my logic and better understand these statements. I'm supposed to find out if the following statements are true in $U = \Bbb Z$ and/or $\; U = \Bbb R$:

1. $\forall x \;(\exists y \; x \times y = x + y \leftrightarrow \exists y \; x \times y = y + 1)$

I've written this in English (to make it easier for me) as for all $x$, there exists a $y$ such that $x \times y = x + y$ if and only if there exists a $z$ such that $x \times z = z + 1$. If I'm remembering correctly, the variable there can change and it won't affect the statement? The first y and second y introduced are not the same?

So that essentially means that there is at least one $y$ for which $x \times y = x + y\;$ and $\; x \times z = z + 1$

In the case of $U = \Bbb Z$, when $x = 2$, $y = 2$ and $z = 1$, above equations work, meaning there does exist a $y$ and $z$ and so the entire statement is true.

Since it's true in $\Bbb Z$, wouldn't that automatically make it true in $\Bbb R$? Considering the same values can be used for $x,y,z$?

2. $\exists w \forall u \; (u \in w \leftrightarrow \exists x \; ( x \in u \land \forall y \; ( y \in u \rightarrow y = x)))$

English: There exists a $w$, for all $u$, such that $u \in w$ if and only if there exists an $x$, where $x \in u$ and for all $y$, if $y \in u$, then $y = x$

I'm having more difficulty understanding this one in the first place... does it mean that u only has one element, and that element is x? Following from that, would that mean w is the set of all singletons then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too long for a comment)

First of all, You have not provided proof that $(1)$ is true:

You have proven the statement only for the triple (x,y,z) = (2,2,1); in other words, you've shown that that the following statement is true: $$\exists x \big( \exists y(x\times y = x+y) \iff \exists z(x\times z = z+1)\big)$$

You must show that the statements holds $\forall x \in \mathbb Z$.

Note that a biconditional evaluates true if and only if the two statements on each side are such that  BOTH are true, or BOTH are false.

Another existence proof (different that x=2): Let $x = 0$. There exists a $y = 0$ such that $xy=0=x+y$.  So one side of the biconditional is true.  For the other side of the biconditional, we need to determine whether a $z$ exists such that $0\cdot z = z + 1$: Sure, pick $ z = -1$. Then $0\cdot (-1) = 0 = (-1) + 1$. Since both sides of the biconditional evaluate to *true* under the assignment $(x,y, z) = (0,0,-1)$, the statement holds true for $x = 0$.

We cannot possible check out an infinite number of integers n such that x= n, to determine whether the statement: For each and every $x$ in $\mathbb Z, \big[$(there is some $y\in \mathbb Z$ such that $(x\times y = x + y))\iff  ($ there is some $z\in \mathbb Z$ such that $(x\times z =z +1))\big]$, is true.

So we need to find a counterexample to prove the statement false, or algebraiclly prove the statement holds for all integers $x$, (with $y, z \in \mathbb Z)$.

Let's look at x = 13. We need to determine whether an integer y exists such that $13y = 13+y$. Clearly, $y\neq 0.$ So we can divide $13y$ from each side of the equation to get $\dfrac{13+y}{13y} = \frac 1y+\frac 1{13} = 1$. This will be true *only* if $y= \frac {13}{12}$ so that $\dfrac 1{13/12} + \dfrac 1{13} = \dfrac 1{\frac {13}{12}} = \dfrac {12}{13} + \dfrac 1{13} = 1$.

But in this case $y= \frac {13}{12}\notin \mathbb Z$!

What about $x=13,$ such that there is a $z$ for which $13z = z+1. $

Clearly $z=0$ will not satisfy the equation. So we can divide both sides by $13z$: which gives us $1 = \frac{z+1}{13z} = \frac 1{13}+ \frac 1{13z}$ so if $z= \dfrac 1{12}$, then $$\frac 1{13} + \frac 1{\frac{13}{12}} =\frac {12}{13}+ \frac {1}{13} = 1$$

But note, $z = \frac 1{12} \notin \mathbb Z$

Comment: Thank you for that thorough explanation. I understand the statement better now. Going off of what you said about proving it algebraicly, would I have to find all possible x, y for which $x \times y = x + y$ and the same for x,z to see if the xs match up? Or would using the equivalence $x ≠ 1$ that was mentioned in another answer be suffice to prove this statement holds true for in R and Z?

Comment: The final equivalence the other answer ends with oversimplifies matters, and the answerer has yet to prove the conjecture: $\forall x \in U\;\;[x\ne 1\iff x\ne 1\;]$

Comment: Note, however, that for any $x \in \mathbb Z$, if neither y nor z is an integer, then we have a biconditional of the form $F\iff F$ which is true

Comment: How exactly would I prove that both y and z are integers or not integers? And how would this work for U = R?

Comment: Think about what I've written; I've spent all my free-time on this; I have to get back to work.  Again, for any integer x for which $(\lnot \exists y \in\mathbb Z(xy = x+y)$, and $\lnot \exists z \in \mathbb Z(xz = z+1)$, you have $\exists x \in \mathbb Z (F\iff F)$, which is true.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to work through it using what you said.

Comment: Wonderful! You're welcome. It never hurts, either, to upvote answers that you've found helpful (there are gray up-down arrows next to each question; you can vote any answer as useful (uparrow), or not at all helpful (down-arrow).  Also you can accept the one answer that helped you most (gray $\checkmark$ by each answer). Just click on the gray checkmark to the left of the answer you'd like to accept.

Answer (score 0):

The first and second occurrences of "$\exists y$" are indeed independent.  We  can insert some extra brackets to clarify this:$$ \forall x\in U\; [\; (\exists y \in U\; (xy=x+y)\;)\iff (\; \exists y\in U\; (xy=y+1)\; )\; ].$$

This is syntactically unambiguous. It is also  bad style for human readers, as they  are not computers and find it easy to misunderstand it. Humans prefer $$\forall x\ \in U\; [\; (\; \exists y\in U\; (xy=x+y)\;)\iff (\; \exists z\in U\; (xz=z+1)\; )\; ].$$

When $U$ is a subset of the real numbers the above statement is equivalent to $$\forall x \in U\;\;[x\ne 1\iff x\ne 1\;].$$

Comment: Oh I see how it turns into $x ≠ 1$. Wouldn't that also be the case for $U = Z$ then? So the original statement is true in both Z and R?

Comment: I think more work needs to be done regarding the last Statement to justify it.

Comment: @amWhy. I left that for someone else. I really only meant to address the first Q.